# Returns to scale and specialization

Tags: capital-returns, economies-of-scale

Anyone care to explain how exactly decreasing returns to scale (DRS) can lead to specialization? Having come across a few studies showing how large farm enterprises tend to experience DRS, I came to think about this but never really understood the logic behind it. How does specializing increase efficiency in such a case?

Comment: Do you mind linking to a few of these studies? A little extra context goes a long way :)